# ios : How to load images from URL to page control using scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm new in iOS. Now I want to load view images from URL to page control using scroll view. When I run the program the first image is shown but when I try to slide to next image or I move to another page program is not responding. My guess is probably related to the size of image.

The following is my code to load the image. I put this code in -(void) viewDidLOad...

```
CGRect screenShot = screenView.frame;
screenShot.origin.y = description.frame.origin.y + description.frame.size.height + 30;
screenView.frame = screenShot;

pageControlBeingUsed = NO;

for (int i = 0; i < [myArrayImagesURL count]; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
      UIImageView *iv = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * i, 0, scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
    iv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                                       [NSURL URLWithString:[myArrayImagesURL objectAtIndex:i]]]];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:iv];
    [iv release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * [myArrayImagesURL count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = [myArrayImagesURL count];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have set the imageView to autorelease and the released it. This should be wrong. Try removing the autorelease tag when you create the imageView. It should be properly retained now.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width * i, 0, scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
```

Comment: thank you very much it's solve... madhumal.. it's working now.. ^_^

Comment: You're welcome buddy :) If this is solved, please mark this as answered, thanks!